# Jquery Click Event not Working External Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**My Html File**

index.html

```
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomPropery.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="btn_cp_save"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save </span>
</div>
```

**My External Js file Code**

CustomPropery.js

```
 window.CustomPropery = function ($) {
    $(".btn_cp_save").on("click",function() {
    alert("loaded");        
    })
}(jQuery);
```

when i am trying to perform a click event it is not showing alert.

Comment: what is `window.CustomPropery` here?

Comment: NameSpace of the js file

Comment: what is `window.CustomPropery` here?   Need to be `function ($) {
    $(".btn_cp_save").on("click",function() {
    alert("loaded");        
    })
}(jQuery);`

Comment: Did you find any error in console log?

Comment: No its not showing any error in console log.

Comment: Did you added jQuery library before `CustomPropery.js`?

Comment: Yes i added before the CustomPropery.js file

Comment: remove first and last line. Give only this,  '$(".btn_cp_save").on("click",function() {
    alert("loaded");        
    }) '

Comment: @SrinivasCh are you able to load `~/Scripts/CustomPropery.js` properly from your browser without errors?

Comment: Alos are you sure about the name space, `window.CustomPropery` feels like it could be a typo for `window.CustomProperty`

Comment: I can't understand why have you used tilde `~` to include external js file. If your `Scripts` folder is in the same directory as your html file then use `<script src="Scripts/CustomPropery.js"></script>` and if it is one level up then you can use `<script src="../Scripts/CustomPropery.js"></script>`